# How to interface with the Apple Watch for the purpose of accessing its internal memory?

Tags: memory, interface, storage, apple

Unlike other apple products which can be directly connected to a PC via USB, the Apple Watch is completely wireless from the point it exits the factory, as far as I am aware.

Aside from a 6-pin diagnostic port under the watches strap I am unaware of any method of connecting the device to a PC physically.

I need to be able to connect the device to a Windows PC such that I am able to make a forensically sound copy of the devices internal storage, in image format. By internal storage I mean any part of the device which stores data.

I am currently in the field of digital forensics however I have only ever worked with Windows and Linux, therefore my experience with Apple is limited.

What hardware could I use to extract the data I need from the device and/or where could I find more information on the matter?

Thank you for any input on the matter.

Although I have not received any information back from apple in regards to the hardware, through checking the device drivers that are available for the watch I have discovered further information on the types of storage that the watch uses.

[image: Memory Types]

Comment: As somebody in the same industry I sympathise.. the answer is going to be chip-off techniques (http://www.evidencemagazine.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=922) to access the internal memory.  This will not be simple or cheap.  Regardless your question is probably off-topic unless you can identify the necessary chips and ask a relevant electronics design question.

Comment: Money isn't an issue at the moment, I'm more concerned with the how than the cost. My apologies for being off topic, I will attempt to improve the question as my understanding of the device develops. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What did Apple respond to your inquiry?

Comment: @HannoBinder I have yet to receive a response.